# Windows HTML Help File not displaying possibly because of security

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, html-helper

I am wondering if anybody has previously had this problem and hopefully a solution. The program I am currently developing is an MFC application and is distributed as an `.exe` (no install shield) due to dependency issues. I am including an HTML Help File: `.chm` extension, embedded within the resources. When the user asks for the help file, it is extracted from the resources as binary and copied onto the filesystem. `FindResource`, `LoadResource`, and `LockResource` calls are made. After the file is extracted, I make a call to `ShellExecute` like this:

```
ShellExecute(m_hWnd, L"open", pathToFile, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

The HTML Help Viewer is launched with no problems. However, on certain computers the pages in the file cannot be viewed. I see a "Cannot Display the Webpage" message.

I have noticed two things:

1. The error occurs only after a "Do you want to run this file?" dialog appears when the user first tries to enter the program.
2. The HTML Help File is viewable if the .exe is run off of a USB (and not downloaded from an e-mail)

Has anybody had anything like this happen? Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I am using `ShellExecute()` because the `HtmlHelp()` call is giving the same result.

Comment: Where is the .chm file stored? If it's in the app's folder, which happens to be "program files", you're in trouble since it's a protected folder. This explains why running from a USB works, as it is then not in a protected folder. To verify that's the issue, is it solved if you run the app as an administrator?

Comment: @eran: Nothing is put into the program files folder unless the user extracts the .zip there. This was not the case when I was testing on other PCs. There is no install shield. The .zip file just contains a `.exe` as well as some other files that are related to the program. The `.chm` file is stored in the same directory that the `.exe` file is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.

[Two security updates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892675) are contributing to this problem. Following the link outlines the problem and has solutions for mostly non-programmers. I used example #2 from the support page as well as the [Registry Reference API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the properties of the .chm file (via Windows Explorer), does it say:
"This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer".
This would be displayed near the bottom of the General Tab in the Properties window.

If so, click the Unblock button.

See
http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2007/04/13/719.aspx
for more info.

Comment: This may in fact be the reason the HtmlHelp cannot be displayed. However, I would like to avoid having every user that experiences this issue having to do the unblock step. Some of the users will not be very savvy, which is the reason for the Help file in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you don't use ShellExecute(), but rather the 'proper' way, with the HtmlHelp() api call?

Do you have active content (i.e., javascript) in your htmlhelp file?

You're better off not extracting to the same directory the .exe is in. For example when the user runs your program off a network drive, you will get the same error (htmlhelp files that are opened from a network driver are marked 'untrusted').

Comment: Thank you for the input. The reason I was using ShellExecute() was because the HtmlHelp() API call was giving the same result. I should have included that in the question. No, I do not have any javascript in the HTMLHelp file, it is pure HTML and CSS. As extracting the file to a different directory: It is really for the benefit of the user seeing it in the same DIR. The case that the file is marked 'untrusted' when DL from the network drive is the same case that I am dealing with DL from e-mail (which will be the primary means of distributing this program).

Comment: The help file is not being extracted from the *.zip, it is being extracted from the resources and I then build the file byte by byte when the program starts up. But if the help file is extracted to a different DIR, would this somehow fail to mark the file as 'untrusted'?